# Scrapy Next Page not redirecting

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape MercadoLibre product listings. I'm using Scrapy 1.5.0. When Scrapy tries to go to the next page, it loops through the first and second pages.

Code

```
# Python 3.5
# Scrapy 1.5.0

import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class MercadoLibreSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mlspider"
    allowed_domains = ['mercadolibre.com.ar']
    start_urls = ['https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/microondas#D[A:microondas]']

def parse(self, response):
    # Prices
    priceData = response.css(".price__fraction::text").extract()
    # Product Listings
    titleData = response.css(".main-title::text").extract()

    for i in range(len(priceData)):
        yield {
            'title':titleData[i],
            'price':priceData[i]
        }
    # Pagina siguiente
    nextPage = response.css('.andes-pagination__link::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if nextPage is not None:
        yield Request(url=nextPage, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

I found another solution. Look for the "prefetch" class

```
<a class="andes-pagination__link prefetch" href="https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/electrodomesticos/coccion/microondas/microondas_Desde_49">2</a>
```

Code correction

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class MercadoLibreSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mlspider"
    allowed_domains = ['mercadolibre.com.ar']
    start_urls = ['https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/microondas#D[A:microondas]']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Prices
        priceData = response.css(".price__fraction::text").extract()
        # Product Listings
        titleData = response.css(".main-title::text").extract()

        for i in range(len(priceData)):
            yield {
                 'title':titleData[i],
                 'price':priceData[i]
            }
        # Next Page, using the prefetch identifier
        nextPage = response.css('a.prefetch::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if nextPage is not None:
            yield Request(url=nextPage, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

The more reliable way is to make use of containers and loop through them to collect `titles` and `prices`.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class MercadoLibreSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mlspider"
    start_urls = ['https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/microondas#D[A:microondas]']

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css(".results-item"):
            titleData = item.css(".main-title::text").extract_first()
            priceData = item.css(".price__fraction::text").extract_first()
            yield {
                 'title':titleData,
                 'price':priceData
            }

        nextPage = response.css('a.prefetch::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if nextPage:
            yield Request(url=nextPage, callback=self.parse)
```